# IIS removes Authorization header from the http request, when the request is from outside my LAN

Tags: wcf, authentication, http-headers, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2. It has the Basic, Anonymous and Windows Authentication modes enabled. I have hosted a restful WCF service in it.

I make an http request with **Authorization** header from my client within the LAN/VPN, all goes well. On the service side I could see that the `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders` contains the **Authorization** header with the right value.

When I attempt to do the same from outside the LAN/VPN, (I used a different Internet connection and also a public proxy), the `OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders` seems to have missing **Authorization** header.

I am unsure as to what exactly removes the header. I suspect a misconfigured IIS. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your service to always do windows authentication as the question seems to suggest, remove disable all other auth modes in IIS, requests from LAN are passing probably because people requesting it are from the same domain, in an internet (putting this simply) will go for the least required auth mode, which in this case would be anonymous.

Comment: I tried to enable the Windows Authentication mode and disabled the others. Then I got 403 forbidden for all the requests.

Further I Enabled the Basic Authentication mode and still got 403.

Finally, I enabled Anonymous Authentication mode and I am back to square one.

Comment: This works. The other issue was that the firewall was misconfigured. Thanks!